# Juju deploy OpenStack bundle just on 3 nodes

Tags: server, juju, maas, openstack, cloud

I’m new to working with maas and juju and trying to deploy OpenStack with maas and juju according to the canonical guide
https://ubuntu.com/openstack/install#multi-node-deployment

everything is fine commissioning work but when I try to deploy the bundle it just takes 3 nodes

[Maas status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DU67o.png)
[juju status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/so7gS.png)
[juju machines status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jraKD.png)

what is wrong? how I can add other node or is it any way to add a new node to the deployed bundle

Answer (score 0):

3 nodes are expected if you did invoke commands like `juju deploy cs:bundle/openstack-base`.

I need more information to answer your question. For example, which section of the guide you followed? Is it "Single-node OpenStack deployment", "Multi-node OpenStack deployment" or "Data centre cluster deployment".

I assume you were talking about the installation guide of "Data centre cluster deployment" section. If yes and you did invoke this command "juju deploy cs:bundle/openstack-base" then it is totally expected to have 3 node deployed. You may refer to the charm bundle description https://jaas.ai/openstack-base , or refer to the bundle file directly https://api.jujucharms.com/charmstore/v5/bundle/openstack-base-70/archive/bundle.yaml only 3 nodes are needed:

```
machines:
  '0':
    series: focal
  '1':
    series: focal
  '2':
    series: focal
```